# 'Sharing' object between NodeJS modules

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm new to NodeJS development and I'm doing some tests with the socket.io library. Basically, what I want to do is to stablish a socket.io connection between the clients (Angular 6 web app) and the server and broadcast a message when a new user connects.

Right now, the code is quite simple, and this is what I have:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');

// Routes
var twitterRoutes = require('./routes/user');

var app = express();

var server = http.Server(app);

var io = socketIO(server);  // <== THIS OBJECT IS WHAT I WANT TO USE FROM THE ROUTES

[ ... ]

io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    console.log('New user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
        console.log('User disconnected:', reason);
    });

    socket.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Error in connection: ', err);
    });
});
```

I want to use the `io` object inside the `user` route, but I don't know how to do it:

**routes/user.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var config = require('../config/config');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

    // DO ROUTE LOGIC

    // I WANT TO BROADCAST THE NEW LOGGED USER USING io.broadcast.emit, BUT DON'T KNOW HOW
    // <=====
});
```

How could I do it? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best way but you could share things between request handlers using middleware

```
// define and use a middleware
app.use(function shareIO(req, res, next) {
  req.io = io;
  next();
})
```

Then you could use `req.io` inside request handlers.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

    // DO ROUTE LOGIC

    req.io.emit('event')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do what you want by injecting your IO var in a function

```
    // app.js
    var app = express();
    var server = http.Server(app);
    var io = socketIO(server);
    server.use(require('./router')(io))
    ...

    // router.js
    module.exports = function makeRouter(io) {
      var router = express.Router();
      router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
        // do something with io

      }
      return router
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best practice, but I've assigned the `io` object to a property of the `global` object, and I can access it from everywhere all across the application. So this is what I did:

**app.js**

```
var io = socketIO(server);

global.ioObj = io;
```

**routes/user.js**

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

  // DO ROUTE LOGIC

  if (global.ioObj) {
    global.ioObj.sockets.clients().emit('new-message', { type: 'message', text: 'New user has logged in' });
  }

});
```